# Does putting state and dispatch into separate context providers prevent unnecessary re-renders?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context, use-reducer

I found that in the [official next.js example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/e969d226999bb0fcb52ecc203b359f3715ff69bf/examples/with-context-api/components/Counter.js#L22-L26), `state` and `dispatch` were put info separate context providers.

What was the point of doing so? Does this practice prevent unnecessary re-renders?

```
export const CounterProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, 0)
  return (
    <CounterDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
      <CounterStateContext.Provider value={state}>
        {children}
      </CounterStateContext.Provider>
    </CounterDispatchContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useCount = () => useContext(CounterStateContext)
export const useDispatchCount = () => useContext(CounterDispatchContext)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do not need to put them in separate ContextProviders if almost all of your components are using both state and dispatch, just make sure that you are memoizing the argument you pass to the provider value when you pass them as a object. This way your consumers will only re-render when state actually changes. Also note that `dispatch` instance doesn't actually change so there is no point in creating aa separate context for it

```
export const CounterProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, 0)
  const contextValue = useMemo(() => ({state, dispatch}), [state, dispatch])
  return (
    <CounterContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
        {children}
    </CounterContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

**EDIT:**

As @dciccale pointed out in the comments, it makes a lot of sense to keep dispatch and state in separate contexts if there are quite a lot of components in your app which largely only use dispatch and hence they will not re-render if state changes.

Even if we memorize `contextValue` with useMemo hook, `contextValue` will still be re-evaluated every time we update `state`'s value, causing all components depending on the context to rerender, even some of them only depend on `dispatch` only.

See also: https://hswolff.com/blog/how-to-usecontext-with-usereducer/#performance-concerns

Evaluate your app requirements and take a decision wisely.

Comment: Is there any benefit to have two separated context providers? Or it is just next.js authers over-engineered their example?

Comment: There is benefit to separating context when context is storing information of widely different things, inn the above case, its not required and serves non special purpose

Comment: I can't find any guide about separating context in Google. Can you explain more?

Comment: I think It *does* make a difference making a separate context provider for the state and for the dispatch. If you have child components that *only* require the dispatch function, and not the state, those components will be re-render as well if the state of the provider changed. however, if there are separate context provider, one for the state and one for the dispatch, child components only using the dispatch won't need to re-render when the state changes.